# html custom select onchange event not fired

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which I took from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select. Where I have to use custom select input and need to call a function on onchange event. Right when I change the select option the onchange event not get fired.

What could be the issue? How it's possible?

```js
function fruitSelected(ele){
  alert("fruitSelected");
}
function carSelected(ele){
  alert("carSelected");
}

var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        sl = s.length;
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            yl = y.length;
            for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<h2>Custom Select</h2>

<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select onchange= "carSelected(this)">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;float:right;">
  <select <select onchange= "fruitSelected(this)">>
    <option value="0">Select Fruit:</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
  </select>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give us a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of some code that reproduces the issue. 90% of the time, this will reveal the problem to you. If it doesn't, it'll help us figure out what's happening!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have typos in your html in the select tag, space after the `=` sign and the select withtin a select with `<` `>`. make sure the template is clean.

Also, make sure the JS is being loaded after the template (including the JS in the end of the body tag).

You could also hook the change programaticaly, using `addEventListener` to run your method:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp